# Problems with installation of alien

Tags: software-installation, cd-drive, alien

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my notebook and tried to install alien (to be able to install .rpm packages).

However, as soon as I typed "sudo apt-get install alien" and confirmed the installation an error message appeared telling me that I need to insert a disc called "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS *Trusty Tahr* - Release amd64 (20140417)". The problem is the cd, which I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 from, is already in my cd/dvd drive and so I have no clue what is going wrong.

Can you please help me with this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might know the answer, since I had a similar problem on Debian once. Basically, for whatever reason, the installer doesn't correctly update `sources.list` and leaves an entry for the installation media.

Edit the file (e.g. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`) and look for a line that says `deb cdrom:...` or similar. If it's present, add a `#` to the beginning of the line to comment it out.

Also make sure there are a bunch of other entries for `ubuntu.com`. If the only line in the file is for the cdrom, you can try replacing it [with mine](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14_RrioI2_AaJyNaUqVTgxDnAI1GRUPkFNt-V-EU3qo0/edit).